# Using Rack::Session::Datamapper

Tags: ruby, session, sinatra, datamapper, rack

mkristgan's [rack_datamapper](http://github.com/mkristian/rack_datamapper) gem says that it "can be wrapped to be used in a specific environement, i.e. Rack::Session::Datamapper".

Unfortunately, I don't know quite enough about Ruby to accomplish this task yet –Modules/Classes in Ruby are still above my head (coming from PHP).

Can anyone offer assistance with using rack_datamapper to implement Rack::Session::Datamapper?

**You probably don't want to do this anyway.**

The answer below is great, but upon closer consideration, I realized I shouldn't do it anyway. Instead, I'm placing the user_id, ip and first name (for convenience) in a cookie and protecting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This gem](https://github.com/minad/moneta) should help:

In Sinatra just add:

```
use Rack::Session::Moneta,
   store: Moneta.new(:DataMapper, setup: (ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || "sqlite://#{Dir.pwd}/development.db"))
```

and use `session[]` object at will.

Comment: Thanks, but I realized I should just put in the user_id and first name inside a signed cookie.

Comment: yeah, that's good until someone is trying to instruments someone else's user_id and taake other the session. beware!